# Joining records of a Python dictionary (read from JSON) depending on key values and adjust the values of the remaining keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary, merge

I produce a JSON file out of a web service I have no control of, and the result is approximately like this:

```
{
      "steps": [
        {
          "start_station": "TOYOCHO",
          "end_station": "NIHOMBASHI",
          "start_time": 1598317440.0,
          "end_time": 1598317920.0,
          "duration": 8,
          "train_name": "Tokyo Metro Tozai Line Rapid\u00a0for\u00a0NAKANO",
          "is_transfer": false,
          "start_track_number": null,
          "end_track_number": null
        },
        {
          "start_station": "NIHOMBASHI",
          "end_station": "OSHIAGE",
          "start_time": 1598318340.0,
          "end_time": 1598319000.0,
          "duration": 11,
          "train_name": "Toei Subway Asakusa Line\u00a0for\u00a0NARITA AIRPORT TERMINAL 1",
          "is_transfer": false,
          "start_track_number": null,
          "end_track_number": null
        },
        {
          "start_station": "OSHIAGE",
          "end_station": "AOTO",
          "start_time": 1598319120.0,
          "end_time": 1598319420.0,
          "duration": 5,
          "train_name": "Line name change, train goes through",
          "is_transfer": false,
          "start_track_number": null,
          "end_track_number": null
        },
        {
          "start_station": "AOTO",
          "end_station": "KEISEI-TAKASAGO",
          "start_time": 1598319480.0,
          "end_time": 1598319600.0,
          "duration": 2,
          "train_name": "Line name change, train goes through",
          "is_transfer": false,
          "start_track_number": null,
          "end_track_number": null
        },
        {
          "start_station": "KEISEI-TAKASAGO",
          "end_station": "SHIBAMATA",
          "start_time": 1598320080.0,
          "end_time": 1598320260.0,
          "duration": 3,
          "train_name": "Keisei Kanamachi Line\u00a0for\u00a0KEISEI-KANAMACHI",
          "is_transfer": false,
          "start_track_number": null,
          "end_track_number": null
        }
```

Now, I'm reading this as a dictionary with `simplejson` and I need to remove all the steps where `train_name` is "Line name change, train goes through", but I need to take into account the fact that they exist.

In other words:

1. No "train goes through" records should be removed from the final result;
2. The first record *after* "train goes through", shoud have the "start_station" field changed to the previous "end_station" of the preceding non-"train goes through" record.
3. The "end_station" *before* a "train goes through" entry should be put as the "start_station" of the first following non-"train goes through" entry.
4. Do the same for "start_time", "end_time"

IOW, if I output the modified JSON, this is what I should expect:

```
{
      "steps": [
        {
          "start_station": "TOYOCHO",
          "end_station": "NIHOMBASHI",
          "start_time": 1598317440.0,
          "end_time": 1598317920.0,
          "duration": 8,
          "train_name": "Tokyo Metro Tozai Line Rapid\u00a0for\u00a0NAKANO",
          "is_transfer": false,
          "start_track_number": null,
          "end_track_number": null
        },
        {
          "start_station": "NIHOMBASHI",
          "end_station": "KEISEI-TAKASAGO",
          "start_time": 1598318340.0,
          "end_time": 1598319600.0,
          "duration": 11, # Will get recalculated
          "train_name": "Toei Subway Asakusa Line\u00a0for\u00a0NARITA AIRPORT TERMINAL 1",
          "is_transfer": false,
          "start_track_number": null,
          "end_track_number": null,
        }
        {
          "start_station": "KEISEI-TAKASAGO",
          "end_station": "SHIBAMATA",
          "start_time": 1598320080.0,
          "end_time": 1598320260.0,
          "duration": 3,
          "train_name": "Keisei Kanamachi Line\u00a0for\u00a0KEISEI-KANAMACHI",
          "is_transfer": false,
          "start_track_number": null,
          "end_track_number": null
        }
```

The number of "goes through" can be anything, so I can't expect a specific length.

Currently I'm iterating record by record as I need to do some processing:

```
import simplejson as json

with open("results.json", "r") as handle:
    data = json.load(handle)

for step in data["steps"]:
    # Process stuff
```

Hence why I'm stuck, because I got lost trying to keep track of the previous "non go through" record.

Is there a non-hacky solution? Note that I also avoid iterating over the dictionary if need be. What I can't do is changing the data (I can add a field to the JSON saying it's a "go through", but no more than that).

Also apologies for the perhaps poorly-worded title, but it's hard to describe in a few words what I mean.

Comment: By "got lost," do you mean you're not sure what's a good way to write down the logic? Do you have code of what you've written so far?

Comment: Yes, I tried tracking the previous record element and what not. I'll try to put up what I made. And also yes, my main problem is logic, rather than actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on what you're looking for:

1. How do I process this data?
2. Considering you're making a web request, I'm thinking the results might be massive and even paginated. My advice to you is to work off figuring out #1 and then work on #2.

For #1, one way to approach this is:

```
# Process data loop
# I will call the "line name change" the "LNC".
new_steps = []

for step in steps:
    start_station = None
    end_station = None
    last_step = None # represents the last step that is
    if is_lnc(step):
        pass # do nothing. that means we don't include it into new_steps
    else:
        if not start_station:
            start_station = step['start_station']
        else:
            step['start_station'] = start_station
            last_step['end_station'] = step['end_station'] # What about appending this? Well, it's referring to what you've already appended so the data is shared.
        new_steps.append(step)
        last_step = step
```

This code isn't perfect, has missing variables/functions, and might be incorrect. But it might help you get started.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do. For #1, there's little I can do. I make the JSON, but the web service in question it's like it was made 20 years ago (spits out formatted HTML): I can handle the service (ugly parsing with `bs4`, but it works), the problem is the downstream logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: I'm not marking at accepted as I'm sure there are better ways to do it. I ended up using [peekable from more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.peekable) to inspect the next record. I also added a `go_through` field to the JSON (that I can do) to point which records are to be merged.

So I applied the following logic:

1. If the current record is not a "go through" record and the next one isn't either, handle it normally
2. If the current record is not a "go through" but the next one is, store away the important bits (start and time, most importantly) and skip the rest of the processing
3. If the current record is a "go through" but the next one isn't, note down the end place and time and combine them from the previously stored record to generate a "merged" record.
4. If both the current and the next record are "go through" (can happen), don't do anything and skip to the next iteration

```
import more_itertools as mlt

iter_records = mlt.peekable(record["steps"])
previous_record = None

for record in iter_records:

    # Extract some stuff from the data
    # Unrelated to the actual problem
    parsed = _parse_record(record)
    start_station, start_date, start_time, *rest = parsed
    end_station, end_date, end_time, *rest = rest
    train_type, train_number = rest
    # Doesn't raise StopIteration with a default value set
    next_record = iter_records.peek(None) 

    if next_record is not None:

        if not record["go_through"] and next_record["go_through"]:
            # Next one is going through: set the start,
            # but don't add anything
            previous_record = record
            continue
        elif not next_record["go_through"] and record["go_through"]:
            # The next one is a "real" one, set the end, and
            # use the previous non-go-through record to extract the data
            parsed = _parse_record(previous_record)
            start_station, start_date, start_time, *_ = parsed
            *_, train_type, train_number = parsed
            previous_record = None
        elif record["go_through"] and next_record["go_through"]:
            # Nothing useful, skip processing
            continue
        # More processing....
```